# Eclipse CDT 4.2 debug remote external program

Tags: eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I'd like to debug to debug a remote application with GDB.

My target system is a FreeBSD 8.3 box with `gdbserver` running. The application has been compiled successfully on that box. My Eclipse CDT 4.2 runs on Windows 7 with recent MinGW installed.

This is an external program I'd like to debug. It is neither written by me nor I do have it as a library. I do not intend to write my own program. In this case it is Subversion 1.8.0-dev which I want to debug.

I have created a simple C project, attached the source of Subversion. Created a remote debug config and attached the sources to the running thread in `gdbserver`.

Now, eclipse enters the `main` function of Subversion but when I set a breakpoint in another attached source file, Eclipse says: No source file named `ra_loader.c` or it simply says "No source available".

Then It simply exists the application.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote debugging C++ applications with Eclipse CDT/RSE/RDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt)

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggestion made on [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/275262/)

Quote :

- 1) run a debug session and open the gdb console inside Eclipse
  ('Console' tab -> 'Display Selected Console' button -> choose the one
  ending with 'gdb')
- 2) use command 'pwd' in the console to print
  gdb's    current working dir
- 3) use command 'info line main' to get
  the source    file where gdb expect to find of my "int main(...)"
  function
- 4)    concatenate the result of step 2 with result of step
  3 (which should    be a relative path) to see if it matches the
  correct source file I    want
- 5) use the 'cd' command in gdb (to
  change the current working    dir) till I get the correct match in
  step 4
        Knowing the initial working directory (2) and the correct working    directory (5) for gdb , I had 2 options: 1) Use gdb's 'cd'
  command    every time I launch a debug session (I could setup a
  .gdbinit file in    the gdb initial working directory to do this
  automatically) or 2)    Setup the 'Source' tab, in 'Debug
  Configurations', to make Eclipse    use paths that match with gdb's
  initial working dir ('Project - Path    Relative to Source Folders'
  worked for me)

Comment: No, not yet. Will try on monday. Stay tuned.